# Remove h2 Tag in screen_reader_text

Tags: pagination, wp-parse-args

How can I remove the `h2` tag used in the screen reader text? I use the following `$args`, but h2 is still in it:

```
the_comments_pagination( array(
    'add_fragment' => '',
    'screen_reader_text' => __( '<h3>Test</h3>' )
) );
```

Comment: Can you add some context or explanation for why you need to do this? The `screen_reader_text` parameter is only for the text inside, not the full HTML markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple issues.

1) You're not supposed to put HTML inside most translations strings ( such as this ).

2) The `screen_reader_text` argument does not accept HTML at all, you need to filter the HTML by using the following hook:

[`navigation_markup_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/navigation_markup_template/) - Filters the navigation markup template.

```
/**
 * Modify the given HTML
 *
 * @param String $template  - Comment Pagination Template HTML
 * @param String $class     - Passed HTML Class Attribute
 *
 * @return String $template - Return Modified HTML
 */
function change_reader_heading( $template, $class ) {

    if( ! empty( $class ) && false !== strpos( $class, 'comments-pagination' ) ) {
        $template = str_replace( '<h2', '<h3', $template );
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'navigation_markup_template', 'change_reader_heading', 10, 2 );
```

The above searches the `$template` HTML string and replaces all `h2` tags with `h3` tags.